# How can I keep my site/image centered when browser size shrinks?

Tags: javascript, html, css

So I am new to the front end world, and trying to get my image to stay center when I shrink the browser. How would I go about doing this? I tried a couple things but I couldn't quite get it to work. Everything looks great before I make the browser smaller. Is it a simple line in my css I need to add or is it more complicated than that?

[My image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ibetK.png)

EDIT: added a screenshot of what's happening even after I do margin 0 auto. Same issue.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  console.log('loaded')
  var weapons = [{
      "name": "44_pistol",

      "damage": 48,
      "ammo": 150,
      "fire_rate": 6,
      "range": 119,
      "accuracy": 66,
      "weight": 4.2,
      "value": 99,
    },
    {
      "name": "10mm_pistol",
      "damage": 18,
      "ammo": 300,
      "fire_rate": 46,
      "range": 119,
      "accuracy": 61,
      "weight": 4.2,
      "value": 53,
    },
    {
      "name": "assault_rifle",
      "damage": 30,
      "ammo": 400,
      "fire_rate": 40,
      "range": 119,
      "accuracy": 72,
      "weight": 13.1,
      "value": 144,
    }
  ];





  $('#pic1').on('click', function picture() {
    console.log('loaded')
    var pic = '44_pistol.png'
    document.getElementById('pic1').src = pic.replace('90x90', '225x225');

  })



  $('.item-list a').on('click', function(e) {
    var current_item = $(e.currentTarget).attr('class');
    console.log(current_item);

    for (item in weapons) {
      if (weapons[item].name == current_item) {
        console.log(weapons[item])

        var container = $('.item-stats');
        container.find('.damage').html(weapons[item].damage);
        container.find('.ammo').html(weapons[item].ammo);
        container.find('.fire_rate').html(weapons[item].fire_rate);
        container.find('.range').html(weapons[item].range);
        container.find('.accuracy').html(weapons[item].accuracy);
        container.find('.weight').html(weapons[item].weight);
        container.find('.value').html(weapons[item].value);
      };

    }

  });


  $('.item-list a').on('click', function(e) {
    $('.item-list a').removeClass('active');
    $(e.currentTarget).addClass('active');
  });




});
```

```css
@font-face {
  font-family: Pipboy;
  src: url('../monofonto.ttf');
}

body {
  font-family: Pipboy, sans-serif;
  color: #14fe17;
  background-color: #292f26 !important;
}

body::after {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  background: repeating-linear-gradient(0deg, rgba(0, 0, 0, .5), rgba(0, 0, 0, .04) 1px, transparent 1px, transparent 2px);
  opacity: .3;
  z-index: 1000000;
  pointer-events: none;
}

.navbar {
  border-bottom: 2px solid;
  margin: 0px 10px;
}

.navbar.navbar-light::before,
.navbar.navbar-light::after {
  height: 5px;
  width: 2px;
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  z-index: 5000;
  background: #14fe17;
  ;
  bottom: -7px;
}

.navbar::before {
  left: 0px;
}

.navbar::after {
  right: 0px;
}

li.navbar-item.active {
  width: 230px !important;
}

ul>li.nav-item>a.nav-link,
ul>li.navbar-item.active>a.nav-link {
  color: #14fe17 !important;
  font-size: 32px;
  line-height: 22px;
  padding-bottom: 0px;
  flex: 1 1 auto;
  text-align: center
}

.navbar-item.active::before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  background: #f00;
  width: 100%;
  height: 26px;
  top: 14px;
  background: #272b23;
  border-left: 2px solid;
  border-right: 2px solid;
  border-top: 2px solid;
  left: 0px;
  flex: 1 1 auto;
  text-align: center
}

.navbar-light .navbar-nav>li.navbar-item.active>.nav-link {
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
  margin: auto;
  font-size: 32px;
  line-height: 22px;
  padding-bottom: 0px;
  z-index: 50;
  position: relative;
  background: #262b23
}

.navbar-nav {
  width: 100%;
}

.navbar-light ul.navbar-nav>li {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  width: 10%;
}

.center-image {
  position: absolute;
  margin-left: 360px;
  object-fit: cover !important;
  object-position: 50% 50% !important;
}

.center-image img {
  background: transparent;
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  max-height: 300px;
  margin-top: 100px;
  filter: grayscale(1)sepia(100%)hue-rotate(55deg)saturate(7)brightness(1)contrast(2);
  object-fit: cover !important;
  object-position: 50% 50% !important;
}

#targetImg {
  height: 200% !important;
  width: 200% !important;
  max-height: 1000px !important;
  margin-top: 150px !important;
}

.pip-footer {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
  width: calc(100% - 20px);
  margin: 0px;
}

.navbar.navbar-light .navbar-nav {
  margin: 0px 200px;
}

.navbar.navbar-light .navbar-nav>li {
  padding: 0px 20px;
}

.nav.nav-tabs {
  margin: 20px;
  border-bottom: none;
}

.nav.nav-tabs>.nav-item>.nav-link:hover {
  border: 1px solid transparent;
}

.nav.nav-tabs>li>a {
  font-size: 26px !important;
  background: transparent !important;
  border: 1px solid transparent !important;
  padding: 5px 10px;
}

.nav.nav-tabs>li:nth-child(2)>a {
  opacity: .5;
}

.nav.nav-tabs>li:nth-child(3)>a {
  opacity: .2;
}

.level-progress {
  width: 100%;
  height: 10px;
  border: 2px solid;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 70%;
}

.level-progress-indicator {
  height: 6px;
  background: #14fe16;
  position: relative;
  width: 70%;
}

.navbar.navbar-light.pip-footer {
  border: none;
  font-size: 22px;
}

.navbar.pip-footer .col-3,
.navbar.pip-footer .col-6 {
  background: rgba(16, 255, 0, 0.15);
  padding: 5px 5px;
}

.navbar.pip-footer .col-6 {
  margin: 0px 5px;
  flex: 0 0 48%;
}

.stat-bar {
  width: 60px;
  margin: auto;
}

#status P {
  max-width: 400px;
  margin: auto;
}

.stat-bars>.row {
  margin-bottom: 125px;
}

#top-stat-bar {
  margin-top: 60px;
  margin-bottom: 100px;
  padding-top: 25px;
}

.w10 {
  width: 10%;
}

.w20 {
  width: 20%;
}

.w30 {
  width: 30%;
}

.w40 {
  width: 40%;
}

.w50 {
  width: 50%;
}

.w60 {
  width: 60%;
}

.w70 {
  width: 70%;
}

.w80 {
  width: 80%;
}

.w90 {
  width: 90%;
}

.tab-content {
  margin-right: 80px;
}

.stat-numbers {
  margin-top: -75px;
}

.stat-numbers .col-1 {
  background: rgba(16, 255, 0, 0.15);
  margin-right: 4px;
  max-width: 4%;
}

.stat-numbers .col-2 {
  background: rgba(16, 255, 0, 0.15);
  margin-right: 4px;
  max-width: 9%;
  ;
}

.stat-numbers .col-1.transparent,
.stat-numbers .col-2.transparent {
  background: transparent;
}

.stat-numbers img {
  background: transparent;
  width: 100%;
  filter: grayscale(1) brightness(200) contrast(0) sepia(100%) hue-rotate(55deg) saturate(20);
}

.stat-numbers img.sm-image {
  width: 17px;
  margin-left: -5px;
}

.stat-numbers img.helmet-icon {
  width: 80%;
  margin-left: 8px;
  margin-top: 5px;
}

.spacer-numbers {
  width: 335px
}

#status.tab-pane.full {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
}

.item-list {
  float: left;
  padding: 0px;
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0px;
}

.item-list li a {
  display: block;
  width: 300px;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  border-radius: 2px;
  color: #14fe17;
  padding-left: 25px;
  text-decoration: none !important;
}

.item-list li a:hover {
  text-decoration: none;
  background: #14fe17;
  color: #272b23;
}

.item-list a.active::before {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  height: 10px;
  width: 10px;
  background: #14fe17;
  left: 25px;
  margin-top: 7px;
}

.item-list a.active:hover::before {
  background: #272b23;
}

.tab-pane.full {
  height: calc(100vh - 180px);
}

.item-stats {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0px;
  bottom: 50px;
  width: 200px;
}

.pull-left {
  float: left !important;
}

.pull-right {
  float: right !important;
}

.item-stats .row .col-12 {
  background: rgba(16, 255, 0, 0.15);
  margin-bottom: 2px;
}

#pic1 {
  display: block;
  width: 250px;
  margin: auto;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Title</title>

  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/pipboy.app.css" />

</head>

<body>
  <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-sm navbar-light ">
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="mainNav">

      <ul class="navbar-nav nav-fill">

        <li class="navbar-item active">
          <a href='#' class="nav-link">STAT</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a href='inv.html' class="nav-link">INV</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">DATA</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a href="#" class="nav-link">MAP</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a href="#" class="nav-link">RADIO</a>
        </li>

      </ul>

    </div>
  </nav>



  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-12">


        <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a href='#status' class="nav-link" data-toggle="tab" role="tab">
                                STATUS
                            </a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a href='#special' class="nav-link" data-toggle="tab">
                                SPECIAL
                            </a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a href="#perks" class="nav-link" data-toggle="tab">
                                PERKS   
                            </a>
          </li>
        </ul>


        <div class="tab-content">
          <div class="tab-pane active" id="status" role="tabpanel">
            <div class="center-image">
              <img src="vb.png" />
            </div>
          </div>


          <div class="stat-bars">
            <div class="row" id="top-stat-bar">
              <div class="col-12 ">
                <div class="stat-bar">
                  <div class="level-progress">
                    <div class="level-progress-indicator" width="70%"></div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>

            <div class="row ">
              <div class="col-8">
                <div class="stat-bar">
                  <div class="level-progress">
                    <div class="level-progress-indicator w40" width="70%"></div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="col-0">

              </div>
              <div class="col-0">
                <div class="stat-bar">
                  <div class="level-progress">
                    <div class="level-progress-indicator w90" width="70%"></div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>

            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-8">
                <div class="stat-bar">
                  <div class="level-progress">
                    <div class="level-progress-indicator w70" width="70%"></div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="col-0">

              </div>
              <div class="col-0">
                <div class="stat-bar">
                  <div class="level-progress w60">
                    <div class="level-progress-indicator" width="70%"></div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>

            <div class="row">
              <div class="stat-bar">
                <div class="level-progress">
                  <div class="level-progress-indicator w30" width="70%"></div>
                </div>

              </div>
            </div>

          </div>


          <div class="row stat-numbers">
            <div class="spacer-numbers"></div>
            <div class="col-2">
              <img src="gun.png" class="img-responsive">
            </div>
            <div class="col-1">
              <div class="icon">
                <img src="crosshair.png" class="sm-image img-responsive">
              </div>
              <div class="points">18</div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-1 transparent">

            </div>
            <div class="col-2">
              <img src="helmet2.png" class=" helmet-icon img-responsive">
            </div>
            <div class="col-1">
              <div class="icon">
                <img src="energy.png" class=" energy-icon img-responsive">
              </div>
              <div class="points">18</div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-1">
              <div class="icon">
                <img src="nuclear.png" class=" nuclear-icon img-responsive">
              </div>
              <div class="points">18</div>
            </div>


            <div class="col-2 transparent"></div>
          </div>



          <div class="tab-pane" id="special" role="tabpanel">

          </div>
          <div class="tab-pane" id="perks" role="tabpanel">

          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>

  <navbar class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light pip-footer">
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <div class="col-3">
        HP 90/90
      </div>
      <div class="col-6">
        <span> LEVEL 1 </span>
        <div class="level-progress">
          <div class="level-progress-indicator" width="70%"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-3">
        AP 50/50
      </div>
    </div>
  </navbar>





  <script src="js/jquery-3.5.1.min.js"></script>
  <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <script src="js/pipboy.app.js"></script>


</body>

</html>
```

Comment: `text-align:center` on the content parent?

Comment: you are using fixed fonts.  Change them to vw or other responsive font size.  look up repsonsive web design

Comment: don't use `!important` unless it's part of a library css

Answer (score 1):

You can ignore your `center-image` function and replace center-image img with this instead and it will center on all devices. The key to this is `margin:0 auto;`. Which sets the left and right margins to auto.

```
.center-image img {
  margin:0 auto;
  background: transparent;
  display: block;
  max-height: 300px;
  margin-top: 100px;
  filter: grayscale(1)sepia(100%)hue-rotate(55deg)saturate(7)brightness(1)contrast(2);
}
```

Comment: That's not working. I went ahead and added a screen shot of what's happening.